# count(distinct(column))

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can run this sql succesfully:

```
select count(distinct(BusinessEntityID)) from Person.Person
```

But what if I want to know this, give me error:

```
select count(distinct(*)) from Person.Person
```

How can I run equliviant sql ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use query like this to get count of distinct records in table:

```
select count(*) from (select distinct * from Person.Person) as T
```

In the inner select you're retrieving distinct records, and in the outer one you're getting the count.

Answer (score -1):

please use directly `count(*)` for example :

```
select count(*) from Person.Person
```

Comment: For example there is no primary key on the table. And there are  duplicate rows in the table. What is the output of the count function ?

Comment: in that case you use DISTINCT(column_name) on place of (*)